# How to output string as a json in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to get the results of a query from php into a javascript object. So in the console i see an error message **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 66**. I know this is because i am trying to read a json when the variable is a string. So heres my dilemma. Below are the query results of a text column called thestartgeom which contains geojson objects (latitude and longitude):

```
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.752067565918,-73.9678421020508]}
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.6908912658691,-73.9961242675781]}
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.7666969299316,-73.9906158447266]}
```

The reason why i store it as a text column is because there are over 100,000 records in the database and i am trying to select only the distinct rows. I know this is a text column but i want to read it as a json object in javascript so i can go row by row and output the latitude and longitude(40.342,-73.221). Forgive me if i offend any one with my question but this is really annoying me and SO is my last resort.

My ultimate goal is to output only the coordinates of the object in javascript.

Below is my code and Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My php file:

```
<?php

$connect = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 dbname=d106 user=b16 password=cccC") or die("Could not connect: ");
$result = pg_query($connect,"SELECT distinct thestartgeom FROM bike");
if (!$result)
{
    echo "no results ";
}

while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) 
    $coor = $row['thestartgeom'];
    echo $coor;   
}
pg_close($connect);
 ?>
```

My HTML/JS:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: "getstat.php",
    data: {sataVariable: "here is some data send with GET method"},
    success: function(data) {
        var r = data.responseText;
        var j = JSON.parse(r);
        var coords = j.coordinates;

        document.writeln(coords);   // attempting to take the coordinates and store it in a variable
        for (i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
            coords.forEach(function(entry){     
                // loop through the coordinates and output the lat,lng
                var d = document.getElementById("fpcoords");
                d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + "<br>" + "LatLng(" + entry[0] + "," + entry[1] +  "));"
            });

        }      
    }
});
</script>
</head>
    <body>
    </body>


   </html>
```

Comment: You have three different JSON strings as output and it's not valid for JSON response. It must be inside array to be valid JSON.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: And i thank you for that @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first JSON is invalid, the three objects need to be inside an array, meaning you need to surround them with [ ] and separate them with commas, i would also reformat your JSON a bit, just to limit the amount of unnecessary data:

```
<?php
$connect = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 dbname=d106 user=b16 password=cccC") or die("Could not connect: ");
$result = pg_query($connect,"SELECT distinct thestartgeom FROM bike");
if (!$result){
    echo '{"error":"no results"}';
}

$points= array();    
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) 
    $coordinate = json_decode($row['thestartgeom'])->coordinates;
    $p = new stdClass;
    $p->lat = $coordinate[0];
    $p->long = $coordinate[1]; 
    array_push($points, $p);
}
$output = new stdClass;
$output->points = $points;
echo json_encode($output);
pg_close($connect);
?>
```

Working PHP Sandbox:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d3c4081edf097190e7233dc49b3f84cbe0ed094

This will output your JSON as such:

```
{
 "points": [
   {
     "lat": 40.752067565918,
     "long": -73.9678421020508
   },
   {
     "lat": 40.6908912658691,
     "long": -73.9961242675781
   },
   {
     "lat": 40.7666969299316,
     "long": -73.9906158447266
   }
 ]
}
```

Then simply iterating over them in Javascript like this:

```
var dataset = /* The JSON above... */
var pointList = document.getElementById('pointList');

dataset.points.forEach(function(p){
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = "LatLong: "+p.lat+", "+p.long;
  pointList.appendChild(li);
});
```

A working JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/workingClassHacker/qkpp333z/1/

Comment: You need to show him how to create the array and then `echo json_encode($thearray)`

Comment: thanks for the answer. So here's the thing,since i read the query from php as a string in javascript there are no commas for each json object. In my php code should i add a comma after each row i query?

Comment: No you should just put them into an array, look at the example in my answer, and the the php sandbox link. When you put an array or an object with an array property into the json_encode function, it will create valid JSON for you. But you need to only call json_encode once! Just pass it a complete object, and you are home free :)

Comment: Listen man i can't thank you enough. A hearty thank you! Cheers!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the advice also. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Espen One more question, I am trying to use the ajax function i created(in my question, minus var coords = j.coordinates and the for loop. ) to access the query which contains the json but the console is blank as well as the page. Any ideas?

Comment: what does console.log(r) say?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1.

Comment: sounds like you passed something wrong to json_encode.

Comment: or paste all your code in a pastebin somwhere and I will have a look

Comment: I believe the problem is in the php code, could you try and output the result of the echo, both with and without json_encode ?

Comment: So without json_encode i get **Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string** and with json_encode the query executes without errors.

Comment: which version of php are you using?

Comment: hey man, i figured out what the issue was, i was trying to access the data using parse.JSON which makes no sense because i could access the data straight without parsing it. thanks though.

Comment: Great! Yes when you return JSON with the correct header, you do not need to run JSON.parse on it.

Answer (score -1):

The JSON string is not valid. The server should return a correctly formatted JSON string. In your case, you would have to enclose the three rows within square brackets `[ ]` and put a comma `,` after each object:

```
[
   {
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[
         40.752067565918,
         -73.9678421020508
      ]
   },
   {
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[
         40.6908912658691,
         -73.9961242675781
      ]
   },
   {
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[
         40.7666969299316,
         -73.9906158447266
      ]
   }
]
```

Also, in the future I would encode the data before inserting it into the database, so you don't have to manually format the output string in order to return a valid JSON response.

Comment: hey man, thanks for your response. The JSON string came from a pgsql query hence why it looks the way it does.

Comment: The user reported a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 66` exception, and we are presented with an invalid JSON response; as a comment itself, it would be an answer regardless. This attempts to answer the user's question, no matter how obvious it may look.

Comment: @BrandonJ what is the JSON response you are trying to parse? What would `console.log(r)` in your code return?

Comment: hey man, i do see Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 66

Comment: The data is encoded. It was done in a pgsql database and i converted a geometry column into a geojson column using *ST_AsGeoJSON*.